# how to solve the error ? undefined reference to `laser_geometry::LaserProjection:

Tags: ros, sonar, laserscan, laser-geometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working in corverting the laserscan data to sonar data. In this task I had I have the same problem as in this question  "http://answers.ros.org/question/31968/compiler-cant-find-transformlaserscantopointcloud-function/"

The answer in this question is to first download the laser_generator package.

- I downloaded it using "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-laser_geometry"

Second add the package to the dependence in the manifest file..
I dont have a manifest file, instead I have a package.xml file.

I added

```
  <build_depend>laser_geometry</build_depend>
```

and

```
    <run_depend>laser_geometry</run_depend>
```

but still didnt work and I have the error:

undefined reference to `laser_geometry::LaserProjection::~LaserProjection()'

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/152431/how-to-solve-the-error-?-undefined-reference-to-%60laser_geometry::laserprojection:/) by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2014-04-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it. what I did is correct I was just missed to add the following line in the Cmakelists.txt file

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
 roscpp
 sensor_msgs
 ----- 
 ---- 
 ---- 
 laser_geometry // This line I added it here 
 )
```

---

Originally posted by [RSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/13151/rsa/) with karma: 100 on 2014-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7